# Is there any way to upload and load Images/.txt file in unity during Runtime? not in Editor mode?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, file-browser

Is there any way to upload and load Images/.txt file in unity during Runtime? not in Editor mode?

I just discovered that the openfile I'm using only runs in Editor mode.

I tried using Application.opn url
and
process.start (explorer.exe

but I can't select files to be added into Unity.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes there is ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Asset: Runtime File Browser on Unity Asset Store

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/runtime-file-browser-113006

Comment: thanks @Mjgholizade , unfortunately the 'using SimpleFileBrowser' namespace is always in red , I tried re-importing using unitypackage and direct from asset store.

have you  experience this? I am using 2021.3.10f1 version

Comment: I'm using 2021.3.14f, try this:  https://github.com/yasirkula/UnitySimpleFileBrowser    , just clone this project and open it with Unity Hub

Comment: UnitySimpleFileBrowser is the way! Thank you!